# How to make derivative variables according to the sequence of data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

df =

| No. | Scenario | Exe Seq | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | a |
| 2 | A | 2 | b |
| 3 | A | 3 | c |
| 4 | A | 1 | a |
| 5 | A | 2 | b |
| 6 | A | 1 | a |

Those are same scenarios, but some reach three, but some stop at two or one. I want to distinguish this.

The "Scenario" values may have values other than "A"

So I will get:

| No. | Scenario | Exe Seq | Action | New_Scenario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | a | A_1 |
| 2 | A | 2 | b | A_1 |
| 3 | A | 3 | c | A_1 |
| 4 | A | 1 | a | A_2 |
| 5 | A | 2 | b | A_2 |
| 6 | A | 1 | a | A_3 |

Comment: Can you specify how start sequence? Always by `1` ? Or if difference is not `1` ? Or some another way?

Comment: start sequence always by 1

Comment: Will the data always be in the order you've shared in the sample? Could there be values other than 'A' in the "Scenario" attribute for e.g. say 'B', or 'C'?

Comment: The "Scenario" values may have values other than "A" (e.g., "B" or "C").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
#sequence start if consecutive differencies if not 1
df['New_Scenario'] = df['Scenario'] + '_' + df['Exe Seq'].diff().ne(1).cumsum().astype(str)
print (df)
```

Or:

```
#sequence start by 1
df['New_Scenario'] = df['Scenario'] + '_' + df['Exe Seq'].eq(1).cumsum().astype(str)
```

Or maybe:

```
#sequence start if consecutive differencies if less like 0
df['New_Scenario'] = (df['Scenario'] + '_' + 
                      df['Exe Seq'].diff().fillna(-1).le(0).cumsum().astype(str))
```

Comment: I want is to distinguish between scenarios.

Comment: @YoungjinNoh - If series start by `1`, simpliest is `df['New_Scenario'] = df['Action'] + '_' + df['Exe Seq'].eq(1).cumsum().astype(str)`. Answer was EDITed.

Comment: Thanks. But That’s not the answer I want.

Comment: @YoungjinNoh - Can you change data in question for explain why all 3 solutions failed? Now with sample working perfectly.

Comment: @YoungjinNoh - only changed  column `Action` to `Scenario`.

Comment: The new scenario should include a scenario “A” rather than an action.

Comment: @YoungjinNoh - yes, changed all 3 answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can you answer a my new question similar to the one above me?

Comment: @YoungjinNoh - what question? If think `The new scenario should include a scenario “A” rather than an action.` it is already in answer.

Comment: I posted a new question. If there are repeated scenarios in the data frame, their new scenarios are not the same.