# create a derivative variable that distinguishes scenarios that vary according to Sequence (Exe Seq) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

df =

| No. | Scenario | Exe Seq | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | a |
| 2 | A | 2 | b |
| 3 | A | 3 | c |
| 4 | A | 1 | a |
| 5 | A | 2 | b |
| 6 | A | 1 | a |
| 7 | A | 1 | a |
| 8 | A | 2 | b |
| 9 | B | 1 | z |
| 10 | B | 1 | z |
| 11 | B | 2 | c |
| 12 | B | 3 | z |
| 13 | B | 1 | z |
| 14 | B | 1 | z |
| 15 | B | 2 | c |
| 16 | B | 3 | z |
| 17 | B | 4 | f |
| 18 | B | 1 | z |
| 19 | B | 2 | c |

Some are same scenarios, but some reach three, but some stop at two or one. I want to distinguish these.

The "Scenario" values may have values other than "A"

start sequence always by 1

So I will get:

| No. | Scenario | Exe Seq | Action | New_Scenario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | a | A_1 |
| 2 | A | 2 | b | A_1 |
| 3 | A | 3 | c | A_1 |
| 4 | A | 1 | a | A_2 |
| 5 | A | 2 | b | A_2 |
| 6 | A | 1 | a | A_3 |
| 7 | A | 1 | a | A_2 |
| 8 | A | 2 | b | A_2 |
| 9 | B | 1 | z | B_1 |
| 10 | B | 1 | z | B_2 |
| 11 | B | 2 | c | B_2 |
| 12 | B | 3 | z | B_2 |
| 13 | B | 1 | z | B_1 |
| 14 | B | 1 | z | B_3 |
| 15 | B | 2 | c | B_3 |
| 16 | B | 3 | z | B_3 |
| 17 | B | 4 | f | B_3 |
| 18 | B | 1 | z | B_4 |
| 19 | B | 2 | c | B_4 |

Comment: What is difference with previous question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71261995/2901002) ?

Comment: In the case of number 13, it is indicated by B_1.

Comment: In the case of number 7 and 8,  indicated by A_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First join values of `Exe Seq` to strings and then call [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) per secenario groups:

```
df['g'] = df['Exe Seq'].eq(1).cumsum()

df['New_Scenario'] = (df.groupby(['Scenario', 'g'])['Exe Seq']
                       .transform(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))))

df['New_Scenario'] = (df['Scenario'] + '_' + 
                      df.groupby('Scenario')['New_Scenario']
                        .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)).astype(str)
print (df)
    No. Scenario  Exe Seq Action  g New_Scenario
0     1        A        1      a  1          A_1
1     2        A        2      b  1          A_1
2     3        A        3      c  1          A_1
3     4        A        1      a  2          A_2
4     5        A        2      b  2          A_2
5     6        A        1      a  3          A_3
6     7        A        1      a  4          A_2
7     8        A        2      b  4          A_2
8     9        B        1      z  5          B_1
9    10        B        1      z  6          B_2
10   11        B        2      c  6          B_2
11   12        B        3      z  6          B_2
12   13        B        1      z  7          B_1
13   14        B        1      z  8          B_3
14   15        B        2      c  8          B_3
15   16        B        3      z  8          B_3
16   17        B        4      f  8          B_3
17   18        B        1      z  9          B_4
18   19        B        2      c  9          B_4
```